# Woocommerce: hiding subcategories when products are not visible

Tags: php, wordpress, loops, woocommerce

I have this code written out that shows all my categories and subcategories if they are not empty. However, some subcategories show up because there are items in it that are hidden. So in essence, not empty but also not visible. I would like to exclude these..

```
function product_subcategories( $args = array() ) {

  $taxonomy     = 'product_cat';
  $orderby      = 'name';  
  $show_count   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $pad_counts   = 0;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no
  $hierarchical = 1;      // 1 for yes, 0 for no  
  $title        = '';  
  $empty        = 1;

  $args = array(
     'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
     'orderby'      => $orderby,
     'show_count'   => $show_count,
     'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
     'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
     'title_li'     => $title,
     'hide_empty'   => $empty
  );

 $all_categories = get_categories( $args );

 foreach ($all_categories as $cat) {
    if($cat->category_parent == 0) {
        $category_id = $cat->term_id;       
        echo '<ul class="parent"><a href="'. get_term_link($cat->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $cat->name .'</a>';

          $args2 = array(
                  'taxonomy'     => $taxonomy,
                  'child_of'     => 0,
                  'parent'       => $category_id,
                  'orderby'      => $orderby,
                  'show_count'   => $show_count,
                  'pad_counts'   => $pad_counts,
                  'hierarchical' => $hierarchical,
                  'title_li'     => $title,
                  'hide_empty'   => $empty,
                  'meta_query'   => array(
                                        array( 
                                        'key' => '_visibility',
                                        'value' => 'hidden', 
                                        'compare' => '!=', 
                                    ))
          );
        $sub_cats = get_categories( $args2 );
        if($sub_cats) {
            foreach($sub_cats as $sub_category) {
              echo  '<li class="sub"><a href="'. get_term_link($sub_category->slug, 'product_cat') .'">'. $sub_category->name .'</a></li>'; 
              }
        }
        echo '</ul>';
    }       
  }
}
add_action( 'categories', 'product_subcategories', 50 );
```

What I tried to do was add a meta-query check to see if a product was not marked with 'hidden' :

```
              'meta_query' => array(
                                  array( 
                                  'key' => '_visibility', 
                                  'value' => 'hidden', 
                                  'compare' => '!=', 
                              ))
```

This returns absolutely no categories at all. Any thoughts?